# Share database in java

Tags: java, jdbc

what would be best method to share a database in Java (I have 2 computers connected via lan), both are windows xp

Comment: read this http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=9

Comment: any other alternates to mysql

Comment: Preferably use a database that runs in a client/server configuration (Firebird, Postgres, MySQL, etc, etc). Then both clients (a process on each computer) can connect to the same database (the server runs on one of the computers). Using a database like SQLite, on the other hand, can cause issues as it requires direct file access -- this would involve using shares to map drives, but that has other issues so...

Comment: i think you should edit it for more specific. (Are u asking that 2  DB in 2 PC, and how to connect it?)

Comment: its 1 DB, shared by both computers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the database is shared by two computers, it really has to be a client/server database. MySQL is one but there are many many others. Many of them don't even use SQL.

I would start with something like MySQL because its free and simple to use with a decent tools set.

A list of RDBMS SQL databases http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_relational_database_management_systems

A list of databases which support not only SQL http://nosql-database.org/